# Anonymous user can't upload file to document library

Tags: 2010, document-library

Is there any way to grant add permission on document library for anonymous user? there is a trick for that, url of anonymous access control page is something like

> SITEURL/_layouts/setanon.aspx?obj=%7BA843FED5-6B8B-40A4-B421-E4B455E958FA%7D%2CDOCLIB

in 2007 if you change **DOCLIB** to **LIST** you can grant add permission to anonymous user but it doesn't work in 2010. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The article [How to enable anonymous access to InfoPath Forms Library SharePoint 2010](http://sshela.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-a-infopath-forms-library/) gives you a HACK by copying the url of the anonymous access dialog and modify the part that tells setanon.aspx that it's dealing with a document library.

This will enable you to turn on all the rights to a document library for annonymous users, but I can't promise you that it's supported (in fact I'm pretty sure it's not)

Comment: As I describe in my quesion I did exactly that hack but unfortunately it doesn't work